# Подсажите несколько "эталонных\адекватных" проектов по с++, чтобы понять принципы построения полноценного ПО?

Tags: c++, ооп

Хотелось бы посмотреть на проекты (с++), которые считаются "хорошими\эталонными" с точки зрения архитектуры, использования классов, правильной передачи данных между классами (указатели\ссылки\локальные переменные\глобальные). Книги - это хорошо, но обычно там примеры на уровне одного класса (Human\Animal) и main функции. Понятно, что все зависит от проекта и целей...но хочется посмотреть как другие создают.

Comment: В С++ плюрализм. Так что по поводу любого проекта обязательно найдется стая товарищей, которые будут чем-то категорически недовольны.

Comment: @user7860670  Вот я тоже об это подумал. Но может есть нечто, где хотябы половина "хороших" разрабов скажет, что это нормально\хорошо. Книги ведь хвалят, советуют...

Comment: Ну вот boost посмотрите. Там правда тоже полно очень разнопланово организованных библиотек и еще самопальная система сборки, но оно хотя бы точно попадает в категорию "нормально".

Comment: @user7860670, просто ради иллюстрации, предыдущего тезиса: boost — это шаблонное безумие... пользоваться этим можно, а вот пытаться разобраться, как оно устроено — то ещё занятие...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Учитывая, что множество компонентов boost стали частью стандартной  библиотеки, с вашей логикой получается, что весь с++ - это шаблонное безумие...

Comment: @user7860670, она же не просто так названа «*Silly Template Library*» ;)

Comment: я захожу в гит и чекаю какие-нибудь опенсорсные утилиты. Мне наприер понравился там телеграмм, А из идеальных - то это код дума https://habr.com/ru/post/166113/

Comment: @Fat-Zer Это прямо-таки какое-то воинственное невежество.

Comment: @user7860670, это прямо-таки какое-то воинственное нежелание считывать иронию.

Comment: @Aptem_f, наверняка это потому, что `"Все игры id до Quake III были написаны на С."` (цитата из статьи)